# Why do I get TypeError: unhashable type when using NLTK lemmatizer on sentence?

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

I'm currently working on lemmantizing a sentence while also applying pos_tags. This is what I have so far

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import pos_tag

lem = WordNetLemmatizer()

def findTag(sentence):
    sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence = [i.strip(" ") for i in sentence]
    pos_label = nltk.pos_tag(sentence)[0][1][0].lower()

    if pos_label == "j":
        pos_label == "a"

    if pos_label in ["a", "n", "v"]:
        print(lem.lemmatize(word, pos = pos_label))
    elif pos_label in ['r']: 
        print(wordnet.synset(sentence+".r.1").lemmas()[0].pertainyms()[0].name())
    else:
        print(lem.lemmatize(sentence))


findTag("I love running angrily")
```

However, when I input a sentence with this I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spoilerDetect.py", line 25, in <module>
    findTag("I love running angrily")
  File "spoilerDetect.py", line 22, in findTag
    print(lem.lemmatize(sentence))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/stem/wordnet.py", line 41, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1905, in _morphy
    if form in exceptions:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I understand that lists are unhashable but am unsure of how to fix this. Do I change lists to a tuple or is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is being caused by the snippet of code you have provided? At a glance, I do not see any instances where you are trying to hash a list, e.g. storing one in a dict or set.

Comment: @Brian the only part i left out was `lem = WordNetLemmatizer()` and `import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685343/how-to-lemmatize-a-list-of-sentences and https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L124

Comment: @alvas neither of these answer my question as to why I am getting the specified error.

Comment: Can you provide the `sentence`?

Comment: And also the full stacktrace, not just a single line error =)

Comment: @alvas sorry about that - edited now to include everything written and encountered

Comment: The problem is `sentence` is a list of words.  The lemmatizer only takes a single word (ie.. a string).  The general issue you have is you need to loop over the words in the sentence for the if/else logic at the bottom.

Comment: @bivouac0 sshhh, don't spoil the fun of debugging =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets walk through the code and see how to get your desired output.

First the imports, you have

```
import nltk
from nltk import pos_tag
```

and then you were using

```
pos_label = nltk.pos_tag(...)
```

Since you're already using `from nltk import pos_tag`, the `pos_tag` is already in the global namespace, just do:

```
pos_label = pos_tag(...)
```

Idiomatically, the imports should be cleaned up a little to look like this:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
```

Next actually keeping the list of tokenized words and then the list of pos tags and then the list of lemmas separately sounds logical but since the function finally only returns the function, you should be able to chain up the `pos_tag(word_tokenize(...))` function and iterate through it so that you can retrieve the POS tag and tokens, i.e.

```
sentence = "I love running angrily"
for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)):
    print(word, '|', pos)
```

[out]:

```
I | PRP
love | VBP
running | VBG
angrily | RB
```

Now, we know that there's a mismatch between the outputs of `pos_tag` and the POS that the `WordNetLemmatizer` is expecting. From https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L124, there is a function call `penn2morphy` that looks like this:

```
def penn2morphy(penntag, returnNone=False, default_to_noun=False) -> str:
    """
    Converts tags from Penn format (input: single string) to Morphy.
    """
    morphy_tag = {'NN':'n', 'JJ':'a', 'VB':'v', 'RB':'r'}
    try:
        return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
    except:
        if returnNone:
            return None
        elif default_to_noun:
            return 'n'
        else:
            return ''
```

An example:

```
>>> penn2morphy('JJ')
'a'
>>> penn2morphy('PRP')
''
```

And if we use these converted tags as inputs to the `WordNetLemmatizer` and reusing your if-else conditions:

```
sentence = "I love running angrily"
for token, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)):
    morphy_pos = penn2morphy(pos)
    if morphy_pos in ["a", "n", "v"]:
        print(wnl.lemmatize(token, pos=morphy_pos))
    elif morphy_pos in ['r']: 
        print(wn.synset(token+".r.1").lemmas()[0].pertainyms()[0].name())
    else:
        print(wnl.lemmatize(token))
```

[out]:

```
I
love
run
angry
```

**Hey, what did you do there? Your code works but mine doesn't!**

Okay, now that we know how to get the desired output. Lets recap.

- First, we clean up imports
- Then, we clean up the preprocessing (without keeping intermediate variables)
- Then, we "functionalized" the conversion of POS tags from Penn -> Morphy
- Lastly, we applied the same if/else conditions and run the lemmatizer.

---

**But how is it that my code doesn't work?!**

Okay, lets work through your code to see why you're getting the error.

First lets check every output that you get within the `findTag` function, printing the type of the output and the output

```
sentence = "I love running angrily"
sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)
print(type(sentence))
print(sentence)
```

[out]:

```
<class 'list'>
['I', 'love', 'running', 'angrily']
```

At `sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)`, you have already overwritten your original variable to the function, usually that's a sign of error later on =)

Now lets look at the next line:

```
sentence = "I love running angrily"
sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)
sentence = [i.strip(" ") for i in sentence]

print(type(sentence))
print(sentence)
```

[out]:

```
<class 'list'>
['I', 'love', 'running', 'angrily']
```

Now we see that the `sentence = [i.strip(" ") for i in sentence]` is actually meaningless given the example sentence.

**Q: But is it true that all tokens output by `word_tokenize` would have no trailing/heading spaces which `i.strip(' ')` is trying to do?**

A: Yes, it seems like so. Then NLTK first performs the regex operations on strings, then call the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function which would have removed heading/trailing spaces between tokens, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/destructive.py#L141

Lets continue:

```
sentence = "I love running angrily"
sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)
sentence = [i.strip(" ") for i in sentence]
pos_label = nltk.pos_tag(sentence)[0][1][0].lower()

print(type(pos_label))
print(pos_label)
```

[out]:

```
<class 'str'>
p
```

**Q: Wait a minute, where is the `pos_label` only a single string?**

**Q: And what is POS tag `p`?**

A: Lets look closer what's happening in `nltk.pos_tag(sentence)[0][1][0].lower()`

Usually, when you have to do such `[0][1][0]` nested index retrieval, its error prone. We need to ask what's `[0][1][0]`?

We know that sentence now after `sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)` has became a list of strings. And `pos_tag(sentence)` would return a list of tuples of strings where the first item in the tuple is the token and the second the POS tag, i.e.

```
sentence = "I love running angrily"
sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)
sentence = [i.strip(" ") for i in sentence]
thing = pos_tag(sentence)

print(type(thing))
print(thing)
```

[out]:

```
<class 'list'>
[('I', 'PRP'), ('love', 'VBP'), ('running', 'VBG'), ('angrily', 'RB')]
```

Now if we know `thing = pos_tag(word_tokenize("I love running angrily"))`, outputs the above, lets work with that to see what `[0][1][0]` is accessing.

```
>>> thing = [('I', 'PRP'), ('love', 'VBP'), ('running', 'VBG'), ('angrily', 'RB')]
>>> thing[0][1]
('I', 'PRP')
```

So `thing[0]` outputs the tuple of `(token, pos)` for the first token.

```
>>> thing = [('I', 'PRP'), ('love', 'VBP'), ('running', 'VBG'), ('angrily', 'RB')]
>>> thing[0][1]
'PRP'
```

And `thing[0][1]` outputs the POS for the first token.

```
>>> thing = [('I', 'PRP'), ('love', 'VBP'), ('running', 'VBG'), ('angrily', 'RB')]
>>> thing[0][1][0]
'P'
```

Achso, the `[0][1][0]` looks for the first character of the POS of the first token.

So the question is that the desired behavior? If so, why are you only looking at the POS of the first word?

---

**Regardless of what I'm looking at. Your explanation still that doesn't tell me why the `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` occurs. Stop distracting me and tell me how to resolve the `TypeError`!!**

Okay, we move on, now that we know `thing = pos_tag(word_tokenize("I love running angrily"))` and `thing[0][1][0].lower() = 'p'`

Given your if-else conditions,

```
if pos_label in ["a", "n", "v"]:
    print(lem.lemmatize(word, pos = pos_label))
elif pos_label in ['r']: 
    print(wordnet.synset(sentence+".r.1").lemmas()[0].pertainyms()[0].name())
else:
    print(lem.lemmatize(sentence))
```

we find that `'p'` value would have gone to the else, i.e. `print(lem.lemmatize(sentence))` but wait a minute remember what has `sentence` became after you've modified it with:

```
>>> sentence = word_tokenize("I love running angrily")
>>> sentence = [i.strip(" ") for i in sentence]
>>> sentence 
['I', 'love', 'running', 'angrily']
```

So what happens if we just ignore all the rest of the code and focus on this:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
sentence = ['I', 'love', 'running', 'angrily']

lem.lemmatize(sentence)
```

[out]:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-497ae98ecaa3> in <module>
      4 sentence = ['I', 'love', 'running', 'angrily']
      5 
----> 6 lem.lemmatize(sentence)

~/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/stem/wordnet.py in lemmatize(self, word, pos)
     39 
     40     def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
---> 41         lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
     42         return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word
     43 

~/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py in _morphy(self, form, pos, check_exceptions)
   1903         # 0. Check the exception lists
   1904         if check_exceptions:
-> 1905             if form in exceptions:
   1906                 return filter_forms([form] + exceptions[form])
   1907 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**Ah ha!! That's where the error occurs!!!**

It's because `WordNetLemmatizer` is expecting a single string input and you're putting a list of strings. Example usage:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
token = 'words'
wnl.lemmatize(token, pos='n')
```

**Q: Why didn't you just get to the point?!**

A: Then you would miss out on how to debug your code and make it better =)

Comment: Brilliant! A great explanation, thanks so much for your help!